# Understanding arithmetic operators in Python

Tags: python, oop, integer-arithmetic

As I currently understand it, arithmetic operands like '+' and '-' are a special kind of methods, belonging to the integer class. They seem different to me because you don't have to format arithmetic operations like so: `x.__add__(y)` but that is what happens behind the scenes when you write `x + y`.

My first question is: am I right so far?

My second question is: What happens in the `__add__` method? I can't find this in in any documentation. I want to understand how this doesn't lead to infinite regression, as I can only picture this method as something like this:

```
def __add__(a,b):
   return a + b
```

but then ofcourse, you didn't explain the '+' away, which leads to the infinite regression.

I hope my question is clear, as it's all a bit fuzzy in my head. Basically I'm trying to get a good understanding of what the fundamentals of Python are. (and maybe in other languages?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does, indeed, translate the `+` and `-` operators to `.__add__()` calls, but also will use `__radd__()` method on the second operand for the reverse. This allows for custom types to hook into the operand when used with standard types.

What happens for `x + y` is:

- If `y` is a subclass of `x`, try `y.__radd__(x)` first; this lets you override behaviour with more specific classes.
- Try to use `x.__add__(y)`, if that succeeds, that is the outcome of the expression. If this call returns the special `NotImplemented` singleton, move on to the next step.
- Try to use `y.__radd__(x)`; if that succeeds, that is the outcome of the expression. If it returns `NotImplemented` too, raise a `TypeError` exception, the operator failed.

Because the Python built-in types are implemented in *C code*, the actual implementation of `__add__` doesn't trigger a race condition. The C code for `int.__add__` takes the *C integer values* and the C `+` operator, which just adds the numbers together.

In custom Python objects, you usually express adding in terms of adding up attributes or other values:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
        return NotImplemented  # cannot handle other types
    return type(self)(self.foobar + other.foobar + self.summation_margin)
```

where the attributes have their own `__add__` implementations, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the `__add__(a, b)` for numbers:

I am no Python expert, but my guess is that this subsequently calls a native code which performs the actual computation. It is implemented in the language in which the python implementation you are using is written in. For example, if you are using CPython, it would call a (compiled) function from Python's source code written in C.

Answer (score 1):

the `__add__` method for number types is more than likely implemented in native code so infinite recursion is not a likely scenario, so your return a+b would actually be a native code call

Answer (score 0):

Well the `+` sign is an operator so it's a basic building block of any programming language. What Python and most other OOP languages allows you to do is to define `+` operators for custom classes. This is done by defining `__add__` methods in your new class.

Hope this helps your understanding

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that:

```
class Test(object):

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self + other
```

would cause problems:

```
>>> a = Test()
>>> b = Test()
>>> a + b

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    a + b
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 4, in __add__
    return self + other
  ...
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 4, in __add__
    return self + other
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

However, that is not how class addition is implemented. Usually, you would define addition of instances as being an addition over the attributes, e.g.:

```
class Money(object):

    def __init__(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Money(self.amount + other.amount)
```

The addition of `amount` attributes within `__add__` will depend on the implementation of `__add__` for whatever type `amount` is, but as:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
```

works you can assume it isn't turtles *all* the way down!